# fetching the data from data base by using jsp

Tags: jsp

how to fetch the states from the the states table in mssql server db by using jsp as a drop down box

Answer (score 1):

To start, create a javabean representing a state with code and name (basically the same data as you have in the DB table). Then create a DAO class which does the database interaction task. Then create a Servlet class which retrieves the list from the DAO, puts it in the request scope and forwards the request to the JSP. Finally create a JSP file which displays the list using [JSTL](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar)'s [`c:forEach`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html).

Basic example of the state bean:

```
public class State {
    private String code;
    private String name;
    // Add (generate) public getters and setters.
}
```

Basic example of the DAO class:

```
public List<State> list() {
    List<State> states = new ArrayList<State>();
    // Do your JDBC thing here.
    return states;
}
```

Basic example of the Servlet class:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    List<State> states = stateDAO.list();
    request.setAttribute("states", states);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/page.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Basic example of JSP file:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<select name="state">
    <c:forEach items="${states}" var="state">
        <option value="${state.code}">${state.name}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Map the servlet on the `url-pattern` to your taste in `web.xml` and invoke this servlet by your browser.

To get more insights and ideas around the DAO pattern, you may find [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html) useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add these imprts to the page

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt" %>
```

Then add an sql query similar to this

```
<sql:query var="stateList" dataSource="your dataSource">
select state
from statetable
</sql:query>
```

then use the tags to create the list

```
<select name="stateNames" id="stateNames" style="width:160px;height:125px">
<option value="ALL" selected="selected">ALL States</option>
  <c:forEach items="${stateList.rows}" var="row">               
    <option value="${row.state}">${row.state}</option>
      </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: JSTL 1.0 is ancient. JSTL SQL taglib is for prototyping only.

Comment: I would agree if he was wanting to do something more complex than just populate a dropdown list.