# sql result set to Output JSP page

Tags: sql, jsp, resultset

I have a sql query fired in my model class which returns a table of user data. Now i need to display the result on my view page (JSP). I don't want to fire the sql from JSP page. How do i pass of the result set to JSP? do i need to construct a collection set and pass it on to the JSP or is there any better way to do it?

Thanks,

-Vijay

Comment: Duplicate questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808900/fetching-the-data-from-data-base-by-using-jsp, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831053/displaying-multiple-records-by-using-resultset, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384189/how-do-i-make-a-java-resultset-available-in-my-jsp, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280034/jsp-helper-class-for-printing-content, etc..etc..

Answer (score 0):

use the request scope to pass from one jsp to another if you are using import
in the **WORST**  case use the session scope but you will be prone to memory leak.

Comment: How is utilizing session scope prone to memory leaks? The session will be garbaged anyway when it expires. It's only more memory hogging, but it definitely isn't memory leaking.