# How do i display database results in a JSP?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a control servlet that forward the request to the model servlet.The model servlet retrieves results from a database and forward the display to the jsp.how do i display  the result set in the jsp?Do i need to write the sql statement again in the jsp?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808900/fetching-the-data-from-data-base-by-using-jsp, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831053/displaying-multiple-records-by-using-resultset, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384189/how-do-i-make-a-java-resultset-available-in-my-jsp, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280034/jsp-helper-class-for-printing-content, etc..etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you use the request attributes map to pass data from the controlling Servlet to the JSP page.

Example. Controller Side:

```
void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
    List<String> names = Model.getNamesFromDB();
    request.setAttribute("names", names);
    // forward to JSP follows
    ...
}
```

Example. JSP page:

```
<%
    List<String> names = (List<String>)request.getAttribute("names");
    // do whatever you want with names
%>
```

Comment: I have my controller  and model servlets done and mapped ,the problem now is what i need to write in the jsp to show the database results.I have tried it something like this but is not working: <%<table class="customer">
            <c:forEach var="customerList" items="${customerList.row}">
        <tr>
                <td>${customerList.ID}</td>
                <td>${customerList.Name}</td>
                <td>${customerList.Address}</td>
                
        </tr>
</c:forEach> %>