# access buttons from jsp

Tags: jsp

i'm getting the value s from database and in while loop i'm writing the following code which is written inside a form and on action calls another jsp page

```
    <TD> <%= set.getInt(1) %> </TD>

    <TD><%= set.getString(2) %> </TD>

    <TD><%= set.getString(3) %> </TD>

     <TD> <%= set.getString(4) %> </TD>

    <TD><%= set.getString(5) %> </TD>   



    <TD> <%

String s = set.getString(4);
                 if(s.equals("Request Recieved"))
                { %>
                <input type="hidden" id= "i1" name="h1" value="Request Recieved" />
                    <input type="submit"  id="i1" value="Submit" />
```

Thus i'll get a few rows and respective buttons. now my requirement is when i click a particular button on the jsp page only the value related to that button should only be updated to database. but i'm unable to relate the button with its respective value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Either* give the button a specific name, so that you can check if its request parameter doesn't return `null` (cumbersome), *or* just put each row in its own `<form>` where the row ID is set as hidden input value (recommended).

Comment: but  multiple buttons are  created based on the while loop i.e  "while(set.next())" hence all the buttons will have same names or values.

Comment: Yes, I know. I've answered how to change it. Just give the button a dynamic name depending on the loop or print the `<form>` inside the loop. That said, your approach is pretty cumbersome. I'd suggest to have a look at those answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280034/jsp-helper-class-for-printing-content, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808900/fetching-the-data-from-data-base-by-using-jsp.

Comment: i'm not clear with how can i get row id. Can you please elaborate the second strategy. I think it could work but can understand how to write the form tag which can have independent row ids. Thanks and rgards

Comment: Each row has its own unique ID, right? Maybe it's the `set.getInt(1)` which you have there? Use it as unique row identifier. Your code is far from self-documenting, so I can't give a more detailed answer. But the general idea should be clear enough: either give each button an unique name (which is the row ID) or wrap each row in its own `<form>` with a hidden input with an unique value (which is the row ID).

Comment: Thank Q dude... I'm a beginner and this my first jsp program involving database connectivity. I am not aware of self documenting. I got it but how can i assign the rowid i.e set.getInt(1) with hidden input field. All the attributes of hidden input are static values, i mean we cannot assign dynamic rowids to hidden input.

Comment: Let me know how to assign the set.getInt(1) value to hidden field.Thanks

Comment: Just print it as value of the hidden field the same way as you printed the contents of the `<td>` elements.